# Remove elements from a splitted string before populating a listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, split, listbox

```
 private void sendBCode()
  {
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0000|ORD|SUPP");

        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

    /*No issues so far, I am sending a data stream in the code above. Now I need 
     to return data:*/

        byte[] inStream = new byte[1500];
        var count = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
        string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, count);

   /*The data I am returning looks like: "0000|ORD|SUPPS|MWH|GGR|MBS" , below I will 
     split this data and populate a listBox with the returned data.*/

        string[] s = null;
        s = returndata.Split('|');
        listBox1.DataSource = s returndata.Split('|');
   }
```

The listBox gets populated successfully, however, I would like the first three   items of the splitted string not to show up on the listbox, meaning that I would like to exclude the "0000", "ORD" and "SUPPS" from the listbox. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
.Split('|').Skip(3)
```

Should work?

You can always remove those after the split

Edit: Not sure where do you get that error from, but I just tried this and it worked just fine:

```
        string returndata = "0000|ORD|SUPPS|MWH|GGR|MBS";
        string[] s = null;
        s = returndata.Split('|');
        listBox1.DataSource = s.Skip(3).ToArray();
```

Comment: I've tried this but I got the following error: ArgumentException
Parameter name: value